# Accessing test info in Google Test parameterized test case (`TEST_P`)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

When I create a regular `TEST` (or `TEST_F`), I can access to the test case information stored in `test_info_`, like:

```
TEST_F(MyTestSuite, TestCaseOne) 
{
  // ... 
  test_info_->name(); // will return "TestCaseOne"
}
```

I would like to access this kind of information when I use the parameterized (`TEST_P`) variant, which allows me to define fixture-based tests.

Looking under the hood, I can see that `TEST_P` works quite differently than her cousins `TEST`and `TEST_F`, as it *registers* the new test case by calling `::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->parameterized_test_registry().GetTestCasePatternHolder<test_case_name>(#test_case_name, __FILE__, __LINE__)->AddTestPattern(...)` method. I understand that the class inheriting from `TestWithParam` will then run all the registered `TEST_P`s test cases.

Is there a way to access (either runtime or compile time) to the name (string) of a `TEST_P`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's actually a getter for the `TestInfo` instance.  From [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Getting_the_Current_Test%27s_Name):

> To obtain a `TestInfo` object for the currently running test, call 
>    `current_test_info()` on the `UnitTest` singleton object:
>
> ```
> // Gets information about the currently running test.
> // Do NOT delete the returned object - it's managed by the UnitTest class.
> const ::testing::TestInfo* const test_info =
>   ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->current_test_info();
> printf("We are in test %s of test case %s.\n",
>        test_info->name(), test_info->test_case_name());
> ```